# App Script Return Time stamp upon button press

Tags: google-apps-script, time, timestamp

Please forgive me I am very new to Java and AppScript.

I am attempting to make a simple time in motion tracker in google sheets. I've watched video's but they are much more then i need it to be.

I am attempting to write a code that upon button press the active cell will return the time the button was pressed.

If there is a resource to learn the beginnings I would be happy to review it there.

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0):

```
function getTime() {
  return SpreadsheetApp.getCurrentCell().setValue(new Date());
}
```

[Date() Object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date)

[Learn More](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/google-apps-script/info)